# oData Patch Delta parameter doesn't list any changed fields?

Tags: asp.net-core, odata, aspnetboilerplate

I'm using Abp Boilerplate ASP.Net Core and Angular. I've implemented odata as per the odata AspNetCore Integration document and it works fine retrieving data. I'm having an issue that when using the patch method to push changes in, the delta parameter in the patch method in my controller is empty, it doesn't list any of changes passed in. The values I'm editing are doubles and the Content-Type in the request includes application/json. The attached image shows the request and changes payload.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add a `[FromBody]` attribute to the `Delta<>` parameter.

```cs
public override Task<IActionResult> Patch([FromODataUri] int key, [FromBody] Delta<Person> entity)
{
    return base.Patch(key, entity);
}
```

Fixed in ABP v3.8.3 and [aspnetboilerplate/sample-odata](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/sample-odata).

Comment: Hi @aaron: It hast nothing to do with the question, just out of interest: Do you use a base-controller with every standard HTTP-Action (Get,Post,Patch,Delete) ?

Comment: It's from [AbpODataEntityController](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/f806f5091d3700f21e6c4d20ee34c5e3cb7bbd9e/src/Abp.AspNetCore.OData/AspNetCore/OData/Controllers/AbpODataEntityController.cs).

Comment: thank you! That was the information I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was caused by Nswag package. I had to get rid of it completely and problem was resolved